# Questions regarding REST vs. API/URI design

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

On Stack Overflow we get plenty of so-called [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) API design questions which are more related to actual API or URI design rather than the representational state transfer which REST stands for.

Roy Fielding, the "inventor" of REST, also [stated](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) that plenty of so-called RESTful APIs or services aren't paying attention to his dissertation. Some only use the term to [get their question to public attention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001799/rest-api-design-how-to-handle-resources-that-can-also-be-sub-resources/39012401?noredirect=1#comment65389191_39012401).

Should we allow the misuse of the REST term for more or less related topics such as API/URI design which might increase the common belief that REST is just a further term for URI design over a HTTP endpoint and therefore add to the increase of the misuse of the term or should we maintain a more relaxed view on this topic and more or less ignore it?

Both, REST and URI/API designs are on-topic for Stack Overflow, therefore flagging (or closing) the post as off-topic is definitely the wrong choice. [Often API/URI design may be opinionated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307736/the-rest-fallacy-or-how-to-prevent-opinion-based-questions), though I hardly have seen posts get closed therefore. Sure, plenty of URI-design questions are similar in their nature and may thus be valid for a duplicate vote, though it is sometimes tedious to point out the similarities or differences to other posts.

Though, the general question remains: How should we deal with inappropriately named questions and tags in the domain of REST vs. URI/API design just because some common belief state that both are the same, which they are not?

Comment: I've lately seen true REST APIs being referred to as "Hypermedia APIs" to avoid confusion with all the pseudo-REST HTTP APIs out there. It might be best to not try to police REST too much, and merely add the [tag:hypermedia] tag when appropriate.

Comment: Is any of this categorization useful? Just use rest when it's plainly obvious that *it's* REST. Otherwise no.

Comment: @Braiam The problem that people never read the dissertation which describes what REST is, so they have no clue about what it is, but they want to do REST APIs since it is hyped. They use this term frequently by questions related to regular web applications which are everything but REST. That's why more educated developers invented the RESTful word, which means fulfilling the REST constraints, but people used that up as well... :S

Comment: @WillKunkel Not every REST API is a Hypermedia API. E.g. you can send the links in the headers or add them in a WSDL or WADL file. So you don't have to return a hypermedia. Imho. it is better to use Hypermedia APIs, because they are more flexible and there is much lower chance that a change will break a previous client.