# Does a user have any practical options for dealing with blatantly incorrect close votes?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, vote-to-close

Pretty often (to the point where I have a canned comment addressing one category), I see close votes that are clearly, objectively wrong.  I'm talking about stuff like:

- Voting to close IDE questions as general computing
- Voting to close questions asking how to do something in a specific REST API as "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more"
- Voting to migrate Android questions to Super User
- Custom close reasons that are answers to the question

...etc.  You get the idea: stuff where there's **no reasonable argument that the question should be closed for that reason**, and often a good argument that the question shouldn't be closed at all.

If I saw people casting votes this incorrectly in a review queue, I'd be able to check their review history for a pattern of such votes, and raise a flag if I saw one (or sometimes even on one review, if it's blatant enough).  However, **close voters' names are hidden** until the question is closed, and even then it's impossible to tell if a particular voter picked a particular reason.  The exception is custom close reasons, but those are rarely used (and they have [their own problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369531/165261), too).  Thus, **it's almost always impossible to find a pattern**.

What can/should be done about these?  My goal is *not to punish, but rather to educate these users* about what they're doing wrong in the hope that they will use their votes more correctly in the future.

We have the option to flag such votes for moderator attention, but with it being so hard to find a pattern, such a flag is unlikely to have more than a single example.  The only options moderators have to deal with this are 1) warning via mod message 2) suspend the entire account.  A suspension is a pretty high bar, but maybe a warning message might convince the user to change their ways.

Is there a better way to deal with this?

Comment: *"Can/should we flag them for moderator attention based on a single example?"* - Why would you? People occasionally make mistakes. Patterns on the other hand, I can and do flag for.

Comment: @Nick I agree, but the secrecy of close votes makes it somewhere between difficult and impossible to _find_ patterns of bad close voting, at least as a non-moderator.

Comment: That's fair... it's usually by chance you actually come across them, or via the CV queue

Comment: Not sure why this question is getting so many downvotes. It's a very valid, well-thought-out and well-worded question. Perhaps the only good answer is "no, there's not much you can do without mod privileges" but it doesn't make the question bad.

Comment: Follow-up question: As a *moderator*, are there any practical options for dealing with blatantly incorrect close votes?

Comment: You can constructively fight that pervasive _"Voting to close IDE questions as general programming"_ problem in a small way. Whenever you see such a (wrong) vote, post a comment under the question stating _To whoever incorrectly voted to close this question, please note that this question is valid because it is "about software tools commonly used by programmers". See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  for more information._...

Comment: ...It's a tedious and thankless task, but there are three potential benefits: [1] You may persuade the close voter to change their ways. [2] You may dissuade other potential close voters from "piling on", and closing a perfectly valid question. [3] You educate anyone reading your comment. And perhaps you could adopt a similar approach for other incorrect close cases, citing an authoritative source to explain why the close vote is wrong.

Comment: How would such a comment be brought to the close voter's attention?

Comment: @CodyGray one annoying thing when seeing such a close vote is that we can’t vote against it. The UI only offers to vote for closing. The review queue obviously is not the same thing…

Comment: *"but the secrecy of close votes"* but when a question is closed, the voters are publicly available; no secrecy.

Comment: @Larnu while the voters are listed, their exact votes can only be seen by a moderator (that is, they could have been the minority vote for a reason that is not shown).

Comment: If the question was closed anyway, does it matter *that much* that you need to know what way a specific person voted..? Why not assume good faith, rather than bad, and all 3 voted the same way?

Comment: @Holger exactly. It'd be great if you could counter votes when you naturally run across them as if you would be staring at it in a review queue.

Comment: Regarding the REST API stuff, there's plenty of questions that do need closing, like _"which status code should I use in [enormously overcomplicated explanation of something that's actually RPC and not REST but our lead dev says we're using REST]"_ and _"Which URL routing pattern should I use for [a nested collection], is it /orders/{orderId}/transactions/{transactionId} or is that considered a bad practice?"_, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307736/the-rest-fallacy-or-how-to-prevent-opinion-based-questions.

Comment: This problem is rather frequent. It seems to me that sometimes people close questions they simply don't like.

Comment: Very minor NB "*Voting to close questions asking how to do something in a specific REST API as "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more"*" This reason also includes "tutorials" (it used to do so explicitly but now it's relegated to the 'and more' bit), so if someone thinks a request is essentially asking for someone to provide a tutorial for how to do some long process, I could see them choosing this. No specific examples, though.

Comment: @Armali The comment would ostensibly be posted on one of the voter's posts, so they would get notified. The comment could then link to the offending question.

Comment: What happens when a specific close vote is cast and the question is later revised, but should still be closed, albeit for a different reason? The only option now is to leave the original close vote or retract it. We have no way to change it.

Comment: @j08691 Whenever that's discussed on Meta, the outcome IIRC is just "leave the close reason as it is", as it's usually a minor issue. Maybe some day we will get the option to change our close vote reason after casting.

Comment: Side question: Does anyone have canonical links for why these and other questions should not be closed? If not, I think a post should be created for this purpose.

Comment: I've seen people on meta saying they use the find/recommend close reason for questions that need to be answered with a tutorial, but it's the wrong close reason. The find/recommend close reason is for *off-site* resources. Asking a question that would require someone to write a whole tutorial makes it Too Broad. I've also seen people say they use it for questions where they think the answer *should* be to use a library, even if that's not what the question is asking for.

Comment: In my personal experience I've found "it's almost always impossible to find a pattern" to be untrue. Perhaps because CR is smaller, everyone steps on each others toes more. Another user and I noticed all the 'problem users' without needing mod tools. However now as a mod (not on SO ofc) it can feel like all I have is a hammer when I'd need a wrench. Mods can't just stop people closing, you have to suspend the account entirely.

Comment: You can see the close votes in a close review without any privilege - but to find the review belonging to that specific post needs some SEDE play. So the information is public, it is only not very well advertised. (And SEDE is not realtime, it shows the state of the last sunday morning). Furthermore, the question history shows the close voters of a specific post.

Comment: @peterh Completed reviews are available in the post's timeline.

Comment: @BSMP The off-site close reason used to have an explicit call out for tutorials.  They changed the wording of that close reason but said that the underlying rule was the same.  People called them out and said that changing all the close reasons willy nilly is foolish, but they changes have remained.

Comment: blatant, low-researched, solid +1 from me!

Comment: @zero298 It was still for **off-site** tutorials. A question that is asking someone to write them a tutorial here as an answer is Too Broad, not a request for an off-site resource.

Comment: @TylerH Asking for a tutorial somewhere else is off-topic. Asking how to do something, even if the answer is long, is not.

Comment: "_Nearly all men can stand adversity, but if you want to test a man’s character, give him power_" **Abraham Lincoln**. Giving indiscriminately POWER to cast close votes is the real problem. Some people just love that power and any suggestion to limit or remove it has always been massively and historically rejected.

Comment: @user253751 Depends on _how_ long. "Too broad" questions are also off-topic.

Answer (score 35):

If you can find a pattern, then flag a post by that user and explain it in excruciating detail in a custom moderator flag.

If you *can't* find a pattern, don't assume malicious intent.  Some people just get things mixed up with our flags.

(Heck, we still can't figure out what the Not an Answer flag is meant for.)

Comment: This answer is **technically** correct, but I'm unsure how one could ever **find** such a pattern, given that you can't view close-vote history for another user, nor can you see which user cast a particular close vote on a question.

Comment: It's not like you'd go hunting for it, but it's something that you'd observe over time.  For instance, a user that is always in your own pied-a-terre (e.g. the Java tag) seems to be routinely closing questions that so much as *hint* at being at an older version of Java as something.  Keeping a paper trail would help the moderators at least get started on their investigation with tooling that could actually look into the matter.  *Flags* can't be seen by anyone besides moderators, so I'd hope that they have something that can alert them about this.

Comment: The problem is that you _can't see who cast a close vote_ as a non-moderator.  You can't observe something over time unless you can see it.

Comment: So...you take action on the things you can see.  If you're *seeing* close votes from a specific actor that seem suspect, *then* you can take action.  But if you *can't*, ***don't*** assume malicious intent.

Comment: I'm not assuming malicious intent, even when I do see a pattern: when I flag incorrect reviews, for example, my goal is to educate the user about what they're doing wrong.  Pointing out that someone is doing something wrong and asking them to do better hardly requires assuming malicious intent.

Comment: I respect the effort but you're not going to be able to accomplish this because you don't have *enough* insight into what the user is doing, nor do you have enough reach/influence to be able to enforce the correct behavior.  Leave *that* much to the moderation team.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused by "you're not going to be able to accomplish this" on your answer to a question asking what can be done.  It feels like you're saying "Hypothetically, you could flag a pattern, but you won't be able to find one, so you'll have to rely on moderators finding these on their own."

Comment: @RyanM I think that may well be the correct answer. There's nothing you can really do. Perhaps you were hoping for discussion around tools SE could implement to allow us to mark a close vote as invalid or somesuch, but I doubt you'll get that. In my opinion the biggest issue is simply that people don't actually read the question in its entirety before voting to close. I don't think we can solve that problem. People tend to skim and use their experience to recognise that the question matches the pattern of hot garbage questions they see most commonly, even if the question is actually fine.

Comment: "we still can't figure out what the Not an Answer flag is meant for." - yeah or to properly and consistently name it as the "Not an Attempt to Answer" flag ;)

Comment: @RyanM You may not be able to see other users organic votes on the profile, but you *can* view votes they cast in the CV queue on their "review" tab, if they happen to be casting them from there.

Comment: It's a minority viewpoint that sees the "not an answer" flag as meaning anything other than "not an answer".

Comment: I don't think this post answer's the question OP asks. The problem OP has is that close votes are anonymous unless the post closes and thus a pattern cannot be easily detected. I don't think OP thinks that these users are malicious either. Not having enough information *is* the problem.

Comment: @spicy.dll:  That's...by design.  Users *aren't* given a whole lot of information when it comes to votes *because* we don't need big ol' witch hunts over the fact that someone didn't *quite* vote the right way once or twice.  There are select cases in which there is an abundance of public information - such as gold badges dupehammering questions - in which it makes perfect sense to then flag and call out if there's a pattern or a trend of misuse of that ability.  In **any other case**, it should be left to moderators.  This is my whole point.

Answer (score 31):

Well, to address your last bullet point (and, maybe, others too), I recently asked a [similar question in SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=53410154#53410154). There was (as you will see, if you follow the link), some discussion, from which the general consensus was that it is *not* appropriate to cast invalid close votes; furthermore, a 'lurking' moderator (after some time) [replied](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53413203) with the following:

> No, never, under no circumstances is that OK. It's absolutely an abuse
> of the close-vote privilege. Homework questions are not off-topic, so
> that is just as blatantly wrong as "I'm voting to close this question
> because it's about JavaScript." - Cody Gray

So, although I'm not trying here to answer your *general* question, it would seem (to me, at least) that inappropriate close votes are *flaggable as abuse of the CV privilege*; and, as such, **should** be flagged for moderator attention. (Exactly what any handling moderator does, in respect of such a flag, should not be your concern: you see a potentially problematic behaviour, so flag it – that's how user-level moderation works!)

Answer (score 22):

There are two categories of users here, 1) those who close for blatantly wrong reasons because of a misunderstanding of the close reasons, and 2) those who close posts for reasons they *believe* should be close reasons.

---

For the first category, education is the solution. As a regular user, you could try the following approach: on a question that was closed for an inappropriate reason (and I'll take the first close reason you listed as an example), leave a comment like

> I noticed this question was closed as general computing. However, questions asking about how to use an IDE to perform a programming task is on-topic for this site, as per <link-to-relevant-meta-posts>

Hopefully, the close voters will notice this comment. If you're sure of the identity of one or more of the close voters, ping them directly. Note that the goal of these comments is to get the close voter to go "Oh, what? that's on-topic? TIL :p" and maybe spend a few minutes reading the linked meta posts. If you phrase the comment constructively (and this might take a few iterations), this is all that's needed. You don't even need to get a moderator involved.

---

The second category is the hard one. They don't need education, since they know exactly what they're doing. Note that I'm not claiming these users are doing this with any malice; I believe that in most cases the users strongly believe that by closing the posts, they're acting in the best interests of the site.

A good example of this, and a recurring one, is the desire to close questions for lack of effort on the part of the OP. These come up on meta, and in SOCVR, fairly frequently. A perfectly clear, narrowly scoped question will get closed, usually for "Needing focus", or "Needing details/clarity", and sometimes "POB". The users who do this know full well that closing for lack of effort is not a valid reason, and will say so.

I don't have a solution for these cases. Obviously, leaving comments as above will not make any difference to these users. If you see a pattern of these closures go ahead and raise a custom flag; at least one moderator has indicated they think such closures are "abuse", and flaggable. There are no fine grained suspension methods for close votes (such as exist for review queues), so I don't know how much moderators can do about this, but flagging will at least bring it to their attention.

Comment: I agree with the general sentiment of this answer, but I'm skeptical that a comment is likely to be noticed by a past close voter.  Relatedly, close voters typically aren't pingable in comments, unless they were the only voter (gold badge dupe closure or a moderator) or left a comment/edit.

Comment: @RyanM True, and I don't have statistics on how often, or well, this works. I like to imagine that the comments are read by some other users who also didn't know about the close reason, and *they* learn not to do it. It's better than nothing IMO. FWIW, I *have* received responses from users along the lines of "oh really, I had no idea", so it's not entirely useless.

Comment: @RyanM BTW, if you know the identity of the close voter, you don't have to ping them on the post itself; assuming you're willing to engage with the user (which might be involved in educating them), you could ping them elsewhere, or invite them to chat.

Comment: ``````"POB"?``````

Comment: @TheMaster "Primarily opinion-based", referring to the close reason.

Comment: The no.2 cases are especially annoying as they have caused change in the purpose of Stackoverflow over the years. It has tilted to a more of a "help site" these days. Questions which would've been closed due to asking for too much help aren't closed now and some other theoretical(but completely fine questions) are closed these days. Either we need to enforce the SO rules better or change the rules to what the community does. This difference in what the help page says and what's reality is not so smart.

Comment: "I don't have a solution for these cases." I do: the site should acknowledge that we're correct about these things. If you do, you will notice the overall quality of the site improve over time from that point forward. Alternately, we could burn it to the ground and start over. But if the site really doesn't want, for example, questions that are directly answered by documentation to get closed for that reason, then it should never have abandoned the "reverse documentation" project.

Comment: That said, a lot of "perfectly clear, narrowly scoped questions" that lack effort would be perfectly well answered by a duplicate from many years ago - if the search were actually any good. When I *can* find any duplicate at all, sometimes I have to choose from a dozen near-duplicates instead. Sometimes the result I get from the search is the end of a long chain of dupe-hammerings, none of which is quite exact. The core problem here, I think, is that answers were specific to OP's context. They need, at minimum, to be community-wiki'd and the OP generalized.

Comment: But seriously: I just don't see how the format can really be expected to handle the *most* basic questions. Does it benefit SO to ask and answer "what does an `if` statement do"? Does it benefit chess.SE to ask and answer "how does a knight move"? Does it benefit fitness.SE to ask and answer "how does one walk"? People who are really starting at zero should be expected to follow tutorials, because they can't ask the right questions yet - even if they can coherently ask questions that reflect their current problems, they won't be ones that help them learn. This applies to *every* discipline.

Comment: @Karl Since literally day 1, Stack Overflow has allowed the most basic questions about programming, questions whose answers are given in the documentation. There are, in fact, few questions here whose answers *aren't* given in the documentation or in some resource. About the only ones that aren't are the "debug my code" questions, which are the types of questions least likely to ever be useful to anyone else, and the types of questions that risk turning this site into a "help desk", which is precisely what we do not want. It seems to me that you are tilting at a windmill that never existed.

Comment: We believe that it does benefit Q&A sites to ask and answer the most basic questions, whether it's SO or Chess. Now, it doesn't benefit *anyone* to have to answer them *repeatedly*, which is why duplicate closure was either here since day 1 or added very early on (I cannot remember). But having high-quality answers to these basic questions is considered helpful; in fact, it's the entire concept that motivates Q&A sites in the first place. As it says in the [tour]: "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming."

Comment: Strongly disagree. If people are asking here instead of looking at the documentation, *that* is the help-desk problem. There are questions where the documentation actually gives the answer ("I called this thing in the API and got the wrong result; why?") and questions where the documentation merely *contains* the answer ("I want to perform this task; which API components are relevant, and how do I put them together" - *some* documentation is able to do this, for common tasks).

Comment: In the latter case, we can help by showing specific techniques that make use of the library in question, in a way that's more organized than a tutorial. You know, the stuff that's in the layer above the fundamentals, where it doesn't actually matter what order you learn it in.

Comment: Re "those who close posts for reasons they believe _should_ be close reasons.": Along with _"the desire to close questions for lack of effort"_, I'd add the _"the desire to close questions because they cannot be useful to anyone else"_. This is often true for _debug-my-homework!_ questions. While the the correct action in both cases is to down-vote rather than close-vote, it does leave SO with a mountain of open questions of no practical value. I constantly fight the urge to close vote such _worthless-but-valid_ questions myself, and can empathize with those do.

Answer (score 6):

> such a flag is unlikely to have more than a single example.

1. Encouraging flags on one single CV doesn't seem wise because there's little to go on.
2. Chances are you'll be flagging a user who might regularly run out of CVs (50/day) and you just saw the 1% of posts where that reviewer made a mistake.
3. CVs age away after 14 days anyway, there's also a chance a given post is borderline so there's no clear criteria.

I think the considerations put together show you'd be wasting the reviewers and the mods time. If a CV is blatantly incorrect and the posts do get closed - and there's a pattern of that; then do raise a mod flag or bring it to meta. Otherwise you might just be creating more problems by flagging than it would actually solve.

> close voters' names are hidden

This last feature could make for a separate and interesting discussion of high-rep privileges (maybe bolstering the [15k privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) by extending the [250 privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)?!). Would there be advantages to it, or would those be outweighed by the problems it would create?

Answer (score 1):

I regularly go back through my own reviews to scrutinize any votes that disagree with other reviewers. I find this really useful both for keeping myself honest, but also detecting patterns of misunderstanding (if not abuse). The effectiveness of this practice is severely limited in the *Close Votes* queue since, to your point, out-of-band close votes aren’t included in the reviewer manifest.

Personally, I see this as a bug since a) those votes do count toward the review tally, and b) will be listed in the closed question banner, should the question be closed. I imagine this was just overlooked when the out-of-band close vote capability was introduced? Regardless, I see no reason why those votes should be hidden from other reviewers, when votes cast directly from the *Close Votes* queue are not.

As this is the core problem being outlined here, it seems to me that this should be reported as a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug)—or, at least, proposed as a [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request). With that addressed, identifying patterns of misunderstanding will be far easier. (In my case, potentially including my own.)

Answer (score 0):

You know, it's incredible how in your list you haven't included the most important one:

- Closing two different questions as duplicate.

And this is arguably the most important one, since it doesn't affect just the asker but every future reader. I've come to the conclusion that people don't care about the accuracy of closing as duplicate, which has worse repercussions: why should anyone care that my close reason isn't exactly describing why some question is off topic, or unclear, or opinion based, or too broad? This is compounded by the fact that there's different text shown depending on whose side you are on, so I will never be sure if the guidance that I'm shown is the same that the asker is shown.

So, instead of investing effort on that, I think that is better spent on making sure that we are closing questions as duplicate against the correct specific question, since there have been enough examples where we tell the asker that the answer is there, but it may be [buried with tons of irrelevant information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/792066).

Answer (score -2):

When something has been incorrectly closed, there almost never exists a scenario where it should silently get re-opened. Anyone sensible casting a re-open vote will also write a comment about why - or at least the first person who casts the re-open vote will (the rest of them can be assumed to cast re-open votes for that same reason).

A sensible solution would therefore be that when someone casts a re-open vote, they should be forced to write the reason why in a text field (or pick one from a list), similarly to how edits are handled. Then when a post gets re-opened, those who cast close votes should get automatically notified.

In this list, it would also make sense to show gold badges next to user names in case of dupe hammer/dupe re-open hammer.

Comment: Agree. Without question, communicating with others via text will definitely outperform clicking upvote/downvote/close/re-open buttons.

Answer (score -3):

I believe that what we need, here, is a feature-request.

Specifically, I would argue towards a 2-pronged feature-request:

1. Cancellation of "in-flight" close votes: users with the privilege to vote to re-open a question should be able to "cancel" an in-flight close vote.
2. Automatic detection of "too many cancellations": the system would keep track of cancelled close votes, and could raise a moderator flag when a streak of cancellation occurs for a user, or when a certain percentage of the last N close votes of a user are cancelled.

This 2-pronged approach would assuage part of the close/re-open war -- or at least, push it in the background until consensus emerges -- and would allow detecting and therefore educating users who misuse close votes.

Comment: This feature already exist, is called reopen votes when the question gets closed. Your vote shouldn't be able to cancel anyones votes.

Comment: Would the "too many cancellations" report the user *cancelling* or the user *being cancelled*? How would the approach educate users who misuse reopen votes?

Comment: @Braiam: I disagree; re-open is NOT the same, in 2 ways. First of all, to get re-opened a question must first get closed: this is quite a visible side-effect. Secondly, there's a big difference between voting to re-open, and disagreeing that a question is a duplicate, or is off-topic: I can vote that it's not off-topic while still wanting to close the question for another reason. This matters with regard to providing a clear message to the OP.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: The same way, really. If the question eventually gets closed-off as off-topic and you voted against it being off-topic, then the system can notice that you're "off-sync" with the rest of the close-voters.

Answer (score -22):

This has been a serious problem since pretty much the very start of SO, and it's never really been addressed: *people cast close votes without knowing what they're talking about.*

Personally, I think the best way to fix this would be to restrict the ability to cast a close vote to users who have at least a silver-level tag badge in at least one of the tags on the question.  This shows that you've been recognized by the community as possessing at least some level of understanding of the material under discussion, which should correlate (if not perfectly, at least somewhat well) with understanding, in a domain-specific way, what material is relevant and what is not and what kinds of things can and can't be given a good answer under the SO format.

Comment: eh, no, it's not people not knowing what they're talking about in the majority of cases. It's people who have a different understanding of what the site is looking for.

Comment: Oof.  I think you missed the forest for the trees on this question.

Comment: How do you propose to moderate tags in new technologies? Or tags where there is very little activity? Someone could prevent users from closing their question just by using a series of esoteric tags there are no silver badge users in. Also, just to beat the dead horse a little more, you don't need to have domain knowledge to know, for example, when someone asks an inherently off-topic question like "can someone suggest a good resource for X" or "does anyone have a suggestion on how I can make this code better", or "which way do you prefer to write this kind of function", etc.

Comment: @TylerH Most questions contain more than one tag, and users attempting to troll the system by using a bunch of tags that never get used would end up shooting themselves in the foot by asking a question that never gets *seen.*  The only real problem with this system would be in new *sites,* but that could be worked around the same way reputation-based privileges are handled for new sites: by temporarily lowering the threshold while the site is still spinning up.

Comment: Most questions I vote to close don't require any special domain knowledge. This would just lead to the site being overwhelmed with terrible questions because there aren't enough people able to close them.

Comment: I agree with @Mason Wheeler 100%. Considering this is a billion dollars company site, I don't think owners need free help. Let alone when it comes to non-professional help that often doesn't solve anything but creates more problems. Indiscriminately giving power to people to cast close votes, for example, is not a good idea. 

Owners have the means and the money to hire professional help. Mason's suggestion is practical and much better than what we have now. That there is going to be a lot of garbage? Let the owners clean it up. Maintenance of the site is their problem anyway.

Comment: The more we need require answering / rep-farming before privileges are unlocked, the more we will have people generating unneeded content.  I know I dramatically stopped blindly pumping redundant content into SO after I acquired all privileges.  If anything, I think there should be reduced coupling of privileges to rep thresholds.

Comment: Another idea is: close votes should cost reputation points. When there is a cost, people suddenly are more careful.

Comment: @GuntherSchadow I've cast more close votes than I have reputation points.  I'm still careful to cast them accurately.  Should I really be reduced to zero reputation?

Comment: @RyanM, I don't know your side of things, perhaps there are tons of garbage questions that I don't even get to see, perhaps you are one of there obsessive closers. But I look at it from the other side, where exactly what you mentioned in your original question happened over and over. Another one of those often mistaken reasons is this "opinion based". There should be a cost when making false accusations. Closing (anything but spam) should be done reluctantly, not eagerly.